# How to run plain/arbitrary SQL with DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I need to run plain SQL with DBIx::Class:

```
select proc_name();
```

Is there a way to do this with `DBIx::Class`?

**UPD**
I know I can do different connection with `DBI` and then:

```
$dbh->do( 'select proc_name();' )
```

But I need to run it within same transaction

**UPD**
[FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.082841/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/FAQ.pod) does not cover that

**UPD**
For downvoters: I know `DBIx::Class` is not for plain SQL. But from one side sometimes query is too complex to rewrite it as `DBIx::Class` understand, from the other side we need functionality of `DBIx::Class`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to `mst` on #dbix-class IRC channel for help.

I should use [`dbh_do`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Storage/DBI.pm#dbh_do)

```
  my @stuff = $schema->storage->dbh_do(
    sub {
      my ($storage, $dbh, @cols) = @_;
      my $cols = join(q{, }, @cols);
      $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT $cols FROM foo");
    },
    @column_list
  );
```

**UPD**

[DBIx::Class::Report](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Report) module suggest another way to run complex queries and get `DBIx::Class::Result` objects for rows as result

**UPD**

Possible [DBIx::Raw](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Raw) will be interesting too

Comment: Note that `DBIx::Class::Report` is marked as being Alpha quality code. So I'm avoiding and using `dbh_do`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to run plain sql and get `DBIx::Class` functionality is to use [::View](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSource::View)

```
package MyApp::Schema::Result::Year2000CDs;

use base qw/DBIx::Class::Core/;

__PACKAGE__->table_class('DBIx::Class::ResultSource::View');

__PACKAGE__->table('year2000cds');
__PACKAGE__->result_source_instance->is_virtual(1);
__PACKAGE__->result_source_instance->view_definition(
    # PUT HERE YOUR QUERY
    "SELECT cdid, artist, title FROM cd WHERE year ='2000'"
);
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  'cdid' => {
    data_type => 'integer',
    is_auto_increment => 1,
  },
  'artist' => {
    data_type => 'integer',
  },
  'title' => {
    data_type => 'varchar',
    size      => 100,
  },
);
```

Here is [blog post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2014/04/views-in-dbixclass.html) by Ovid